# Why docker container can see all GPU devices on the host?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, nvidia

Host O/S Version: CentOS 7.3

Docker Version:1.12.6

CUDA Version 8.0.61

There are 4 GPUs on the host machine. Below are the details:

```
"Devices": [
                {
                    "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidiactl",
                    "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidiactl",
                    "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
                },
                {
                    "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidia-uvm",
                    "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidia-uvm",
                    "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
                },
                {
                    "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidia2",
                    "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidia0",
                    "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
                },
                {
                    "PathOnHost": "/dev/fuse",
                    "PathInContainer": "/dev/fuse",
                    "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
                }
            ],
```

See below the list of Nvidia devices:

```
root@de-18--dev-105631-3244950001-48pjz:/sys/fs/cgroup/devices# ls /dev | grep nv
    nvidia-uvm
    nvidia-uvm-tools
    nvidia0
    nvidia1
    nvidia2
    nvidia3
    nvidiactl
root@de-18--dev-105631-3244950001-48pjz:/sys/fs/cgroup/devices# cat devices.list 
    a *:* rwm
```

Container is not running on the privileged mode. When the number of GPU is correct in the container, but sometime later there we can see 4 GPUs in then container.

Answer (score 2):

Containers are an abstraction at the app layer that packages code and dependencies together. Multiple containers can run on the same machine and share the OS kernel with other containers, each running as isolated processes in user space. While Virtual machines (VMs) are an abstraction of physical hardware turning one server into many servers. This is the reason you are able to see all the GPU's listed on the Host.

Use "docker stats" for finding out Container's resource usage (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/)